# First law of thermodynamic for a system in two equilibrium states

Tags: thermodynamics

The first Law is:

$dE=dQ+dW$

Now if our system jumps from state A to state B and we integrate the above equation, we will get:

$\Delta E= \Delta Q + \Delta W$

I can understand that $\Delta E = E_b - E_a$

But if we use the same logic then it means that:

$\Delta Q = Q_b - Q_a$. But this doesn't make sense, since heat is not a state variable. What it means to do the difference between heat  the system is in the state B and the heat when the system is in state A. Am I understanding the symbol $\Delta Q$ wrong?

Comment: You are understanding Q wrong.  Q represents the heat transferred to the system from  the surroundings, across the boundary between the system and surroundings; it is not equal to the energy in the system.  That is E.

Comment: Confusion can be avoided by integrating to obtain $\Delta E=Q+W$, where Q represents the energy gained by heating. “Change in heat” isn’t really meaningful in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first Law is:
>
> $dE=dQ+dW$

Internal energy is a state function. Changes between two states do not depend on the path (process(es)) connecting the states. Thus it is an exact differential.  Heat and work are amounts of energy being transferred, they are path dependent and not properties of the system.  Consequently they are inexact differentials. The equation should be written as

$$dE=\delta Q+\delta W$$

Where $\delta$ means a small quantity of energy being transferred.

> Now if our system jumps from state A to state B and we integrate the
> above equation, we will get:
>
> $\Delta E= \Delta Q + \Delta W$

Again, heat and work are not "changes" in properties. They are processes that result in the transfer of energy. The equation should be written as

$$\Delta E=Q+W$$

where  $Q$ is understood to be positive if energy is transferred to the system in the form of heat and $W$ is understood to positive if energy transferred to the system (work done on the system).

> I can understand that $\Delta E = E_b - E_a$
>
> But if we use the same logic then it means that:
>
> $\Delta Q = Q_b - Q_a$

Your logic is faulty because again heat is not a property of the system so a  "change" in heat has no meaning.

> Am I understanding the symbol $\Delta Q$ wrong?

Yes, because again there is not "change" in heat because heat is not a property of the system. It is not the energy itself but the mechanism for transferring energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so basically I was doing a notation mistake, hence the confusion?

Comment: Yes, but it is not a trivial mistake. Internal energy, temperature, pressure, volume, etc. are properties of a system that can change (thus the $\Delta$ and $d$) between equilibrium states, but do not depend on the path between the states. Heat and work are not system properties. They do not change. The amount of heat or work transfer does depend on the path between states (thus the $\delta$).

Comment: Yes I understand, thanks

Comment: But if this is true $\delta W = -pdV$ what we are doing here is relating state variables with something which is not, and if we were to integrate what would the boundaries for the left side of the integral be? I know that for the right side (assuming isobar process) the boundaries would be the volumes in the beginning and in the end

Comment: And if we assume that Pressure doesn't change, but it's constant, then in the right side you would get $p\Delta V$ and in the left side, since it's path dependent you would get what?

Comment: @imbAF In order to be able to integrate the right side you need to know how pressure varies with volume and that depends on the path between two equilibrium states. Therefore,  is a path function. If you say it is an isobaric process, then you have defined the path. But an isobaric process is not the only possible path between two equilibrium states. You can connect the same two pressure states with an infinite number of paths, each involving a different amount of work.

Comment: @imbAF I'll be away for a while so I won't be able to follow up with you until later.

Comment: @imbAF I'm back. Did my last comment answer your previous question?

Comment: Yes it did. But I do have additional questions, in the near future regarding thermodynamics. It would have been better if we could chat, whenever you have time

Comment: @imbAF Sure. But I'd like to restrict it to chat involving an answer I am working on for a question of yours.

Comment: Ok sure. Currently I am busy, but I don't know how to contact you once I have time. Is there  a way? By chatting it will get easier for me to understand the many not explained things in our lectures

Comment: @imbAF Do you know how to set up a Chat room? See the Chat link at the bottom of every post. Then just invite me.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the confusion originates from using the notation $dW$ and $dQ$ to indicate the transferred heat and work done in the transformation resulting in a change of internal energy $dU$. This is a relatively widespread poor notation, because, in general, $dW$ and $dQ$ are process-dependent quantities that cannot be expressed as functions of the system's state variables.

The only justification for this notation is that if the difference of internal energy is small enough, and considering that $U$ is a state function, it is possible to find a quasi-static and reversible path connecting the same two states. Along such a path, it is possible to write two explicit functions for $dW$ and $dQ$ in terms of the state variables (for instance, $-pdV+TdS$). However, it is important to bear in mind that the quantities $dW$ and $dQ$ on the actual path may be completely different from $-pdV$ and $TdS$ on the quasi-static and reversible path.

To summarize, yes, if $\Delta$ is for difference, the symbols $\Delta Q$ and $\Delta W$ are wrong.

Comment: "However, it is important to bear in mind that the quantities dW and dQ on the actual path may be completely different from −pdV and TdS on the quasi-static and reversible path." Can you explain this part. I don't understand what you are trying to say. But I did understand that if the process is quasi-static/rev we can express work and heat as functions of state variables.

Comment: @imbAF I mean that only the sum of work and heat is a state function. Therefore, whatever is the transformation (reversible or not) dU between two states is always the same. Separately, W and Q depend on the transformation.